# How do I catch an error from Observable in Firestore?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I have the following method in Angular (9) which attempts to find a document in firestore based on an id. However, if the document does not exist in firestore, I want to have a custom message for the user. I tried 3 different ways to catch errors, summarized in this code:

```
  joinGame(name, gameID): void {
    this.changeName(name);
    if (this.nameValid(name)) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('gameID', gameID);
      this.ws.joinGame(gameID, name);
      try {
        const gameDoc = this.afs.doc('games/' + gameID);
        const game = gameDoc.valueChanges();
        game.pipe(catchError => of([])).subscribe(data => {
          //@ts-ignore
          this.localGame = data.game;
        }, err => console.log(err));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    } else {
      this.nameError = true;
    }
  }
```

1- try-catch

2- catch after subscribe

3- catchError (I don't actually know what this is but I thought to try it anyway).

Anyway, none of these seemed to console.log what I wanted or handle the error gracefully. The console just gave the default error no matter what I logged. I know I can also just try not even let the user enter an invalid ID with a check before subscribing, but I was wondering if there is a better solution for doing this more automatically? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a better way to do that instead of relying on catching an error, that is because after you use `.doc('someId').get()` you can already check if the resulting document exists or not, without throwing errors. So I would change the code you have to the following:

```
joinGame(name, gameID): void {
    this.changeName(name);
    if (this.nameValid(name)) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('gameID', gameID);
        this.ws.joinGame(gameID, name);
        try {
            const gameDoc = this.afs.doc('games/' + gameID).get().then(docSnapshot => {
                if(docSnapshot.exists){
                    const game = gameDoc.valueChanges();
                    game.subscribe(data => {
                        //@ts-ignore
                        this.localGame = data.game;
                    }
                }else{
                    console.log("The document does not exist in the Firestore");
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    } else {
        this.nameError = true;
    }
}
```